# pyGrub instant start

Tags: centos

I'm am currently using /usr/bin/pygrub for the bootloader of a xen DomU. What do I need to modify to get it so that pyGrub will just pick the default Operating System? I'd prefer to save those 5 seconds waiting for a user prompt, since there is only 1 option and it won't be run manually anyway.

This is for a Centos 5.8 Xen DomU.

Comment: I figured it out.

In /boot/grub/grub.conf there is an option for timeout, which can be set to timeout=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/boot/grub/grub.conf` there is an option for `timeout`, which can be set to `timeout=0`